# Dynamically created menu in fluid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a task to create dynamic menu.For that I used the below code

```
 //For Menu Count
    var countMenu = $('#topMenu ul li').length;
    var topMenuWidth = $('#topMenu').width(); 
    var percentage = topMenuWidth / countMenu;
    $('#topMenu ul li').css('width', percentage);
    $('#adminChild .columnDiv').css('width', percentage);
```

But its working for pixel width mmenus.I want to make the menu responsive.When I doing that its not taking the actual width.
Css is

```
#topMenu
{
    float: left;
    height: 51px;
    width:97%;
}
#topMenu ul
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

In the output I can see like this

```
<li id="1" style="width: 109.143px;">
```

Also the last menu is missed.How can I solve this problem..Is there anyotherway to create menu dynamically?
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DMMCF/1/)

Comment: Show your working demo in fiddle

Comment: @Sowmya- the menu is created from json file.How can i upload it to fiddle

Comment: create fiddle with the rendered html code and related css coz here your question is about alignment so need not to worry about dynamically loading

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DMMCF/1/

Comment: If I got you right http://jsfiddle.net/DMMCF/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS**

```
   var percentage = 100/countMenu
```

OR

```
var percentage =countMenu/topMenuWidth*1000;
```

OR

```
  var widthPerElement = topMenuWidth/countMenu
  var percentage = widthPerElement/topMenuWidth *100
```

this would convent the width according to PERCENTAGE